# Repeatable custom field display

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I've got this far with some PHP to display a repeatable field but the output just displayed Array

Any ideas would be greatly appreaciated:

```
<?php
$repeatable = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_eventdaytime', true);
if( !empty($repeatable )) {
    echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Time.gif">';
    echo $repeatable ;
    echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: If the "single" argument is true when using `get_post_meta()` that means the meta data is stored as an array.

Comment: Use print_r($repeatable) to see (and post here) what you get from custom field.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $repeatable = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "ecpt_eventdaytime", true ); 
        echo $repeatable ;
      endwhile;
      endif;
?>
```

Or if you want to display a custom field value outside the loop, simply use the following code. The thing is, you simply need the ID.

```
<?php 
    global $wp_query;
    $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
    echo get_post_meta($postid, 'ecpt_eventdaytime', true);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @RTB - that still unfortunately displays just the ARRAY

Comment: If it's still an array why don't you just: `<?php echo $repeatable[0]; ?>` grab the value from it?

Comment: thanks RTB!!!
I have a problem displaying the 2nd repeatable field...e.g. the below code outputs the img followed by the 1st field but then, regardless of whether the second repeatable field is present, the 2nd img appears:

`<?php if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
        $repeatable = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), "ecpt_eventdaytime", true ); 
        echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Time.gif">';
  echo $repeatable[0];
  echo "<br>";
      endwhile;
      endif;
   echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Time.gif">';
echo $repeatable[1];
?>`

Comment: Check the type of the field: `<?php var_dump($repeatable[1]); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

because [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) return array you need to use loop

> Quoting from [**wordpress**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta#Return_Value)
>
> `<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> - If only $id is set it will return all meta values in an associative array.
> - If $single is set to false, or left blank, the function returns an array containing all values of the specified key.
> - If $single is set to true, the function returns the first value of the specified key (not in an array)

Answer (score 0):

If `ecpt_eventdaytime` is array then:

```
<?php
$repeatable = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_eventdaytime', true);
if( !empty($repeatable )) {
    foreach($repeatable as $value) {
        echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Time.gif">';
        echo $value;
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
?>
```